# Swift Mailer on Symfony 3.4, configuration

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

This is what I see with `php bin/console debug:config swiftmailer`:

[image]

I can send emails with `php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send` they are sent ok:

[image]

Here is the email in my account:

[image]

But I can't do it with my controller on Symfony. I have tested many examples, none one works. I have tested on dev and prod enviroment (here mainly, here is where I need it of course). This is an example of my code:

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request ) {

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Some Subject')
    ->setFrom('example@gmail.com')
    ->setTo('myemail@gmail.com')
    ->setBody('asdas');

    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    dump($message);
    die();
```

I can see the full message in the output but no email is sent.

I have tested also this way:

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
          ->setFrom(['john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'])
          ->setTo(['myemail@gmail.com' => 'A name'])
          ->setBody('Here is the message itself');

$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Same, nothing happens. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the spool option which delays the sending emails. Disable the spool or remove the die().

https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html

When you use Swiftmail spool it saves the email to send it during the termination event ( https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-terminate-event ) which in your case it is not happening as you are killing the script with `die();` in your last line.

> kernel.terminate in the Symfony Framework
>
> If you use the memory spooling option of the default Symfony mailer, then the EmailSenderListener is activated, which actually delivers any emails that you scheduled to send during the request.

Comment: I tested with smtp (as transporter) from gmail and it works everything ok, with the same code on the controller, so how would affect the die() there? I can't use the `mail` transporter, but I need it because I don't must use external smtps for emails, even though I know that `mail`is deprecated, but I tried with `sendmail` but I can't get it neither, and at least as I posted I know I can send emails with `mail`

Comment: You should not kill unexpectedly a Symfony application unless you fully understand the consequences. This is one of the cases. I really encourage you to remove the die(). Although removing the spool part of your setup will fix your issue. Please check the doc attached to the solution to understand what it is going on.